# After updatet documentDB sdk .net to 1.10.0 or latest method not found

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, sdk, azure-cosmosdb

After update Document Db SDK .NET to 1.10.0 or latest, exception by login.

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedResponse`1<!!0>> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.IDocumentQuery`1.ExecuteNextAsync()'.]
   DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity.<GetUsers>d__9.MoveNext() +0
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine) +94
   DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity.UserStore`1.GetUsers(Expression`1 predicate) +146
   DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity.<FindByNameAsync>d__17.MoveNext() +366
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindAsync>d__12.MoveNext() +267
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   Rezzame.Providers.<GrantResourceOwnerCredentials>d__2.MoveNext() in D:\Project\rezzame\Rezzame\Providers\ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs:39
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeTokenEndpointResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrantAsync>d__3f.MoveNext() +466
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__22.MoveNext() +1548
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +1103
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +435
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +638
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +404
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +180
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs here error occurs

```
Line 39:             ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName.ToLower(), context.Password);
```

Init user manager

```
 public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"], "Users"));
```

DocumentDB ASP.Net Identity is v1.0.10-beta

NOTE: some methods do not work in the SDK to get data, after updating all SDK in the project they started to work but did not work login.

Someone has idea what it could be?

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, please mark it that will help more communities have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested DocumentDB ASP.Net Identity[v1.0.10-beta] with [demo code](https://github.com/tracker086/DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity/tree/master/samples). It works correctly on my side. The following is my detail steps. Please refer to check it.

1. Download the [demo code](https://github.com/tracker086/DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity/tree/master/samples) from the github
2. Change the IdentityConfig with my documentdb info

[image]

3. Run the demo code local and registry a user. Then I can find the user can login and get the registried user from the Azure portal

[image]

4.In the package manager console (View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console) type in :

```
Install-Package DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity -Pre
```

5. Try to login with the registried user

[image]

6. According to error info,update the Newtonsoft.Json version  to 10.0.2
7. Registry another user using customized collection

[image]

8. Login with the registried user successfully.

[image]

Comment: I am getting error `cannot convert from 'System.Uri' to 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient'` I am using `DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity 1.0.10-beta` and `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.12.2`

Comment: If you it is possible, please share your code or  rasie another SO thread.